# python findall finds only the last occurrence

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract some data from webpage using Python 2.7.5.

code:

```
p = re.compile(r'.*<section\s*id="(.+)">(.+)</section>.*')
str = 'df  <section id="1">2</section> fdd <section id="3">4</section> fd'
m = p.findall(str)
for eachentry in m:
    print 'id=[{}], text=[{}]'.format(eachentry[0], eachentry[1])
```

output:

```
id=[3], text=[4]
```

why it's extracting only the last occurrence? if i remove the last occurrence the first one is found

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.*` at the beginning is very greedy and it consumes till the last occurrence. In fact all the `.*` in the expression are very greedy. So, we make them non-greedy with `?`, like this

```
p = re.compile(r'.*?<section\s*id="(.+?)">(.+?)</section>.*?')
```

And the output becomes

```
id=[1], text=[2]
id=[3], text=[4]
```

In fact, you can drop the first and last `.*` patterns and keep it simple like this

```
p = re.compile(r'<section\s*id="(.+?)">(.+?)</section>')
```

Comment: how should it be changed if str is multiline string? If i add , compile( .. , re.MULTILINE) nothing is found, but if i replace('\n', '') in str before everything is found ok

Comment: found myself: needed to use re.DOTALL flag

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression needs to be changed as follows:

```
p = re.compile(r'<section\s*id="(.+?)">(.+?)</section>')
```